# Song refrain in "Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince"

Tags: harry-potter, music-identification

I'm looking for the name of this song from *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*.

It plays towards the end of the hilarious scene where Ron has eaten the love-potion laced chocolates.

The song overlays where Ron returns to sitting on the floor pining to the moon.

The complete track is called 'Ron in Love' and is from the recording sessions and is not on the OST.

The piece I'm looking for is a snippet within this track at the 1m24s mark in the linked video (you hear it played as bells).

I believe it is popular song refrain.

Does anyone know the name of this song..?

[*Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VMy-erDsDw)

Answer (score 5):

Apparently it isn't from a popular song. It was composed by Nicholas Hooper for the scene *Ron In Love* and is titled *Moonlit Night* The full song can be heard here:

[Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince (2009) - Full Expanded soundtrack](https://youtu.be/jDSSSa_TU18?t=4071)

Comment: Yes, that's the score I'm listening to as well (thanks for this link though). But, using the link you provided, if you listen specifically to 1:08:02 - 1:08:12 those dozen or so notes are from--or a very, very similar to--a popular song. Perhaps this is a coincidence and not intentional on Hooper's part; but, it's this section/refrain that I'm trying to identify (even if simply similar).

Answer (score 1):

This is the song that this refrain--the music box snippet--reminded me of: *The Zombies* '[The Way I feel Inside](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QG1frfRywc)' (also [Taron Egerton's version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zuub9EFyM4) in *Sing*).

It's not identical, I know; but, there's a few notes that match this song and how--in both versions--the voice follows the melody.

It's this section that is reproduced in *Harry potter and the Half-Blood Prince* 'Ron in Love' (also, 'Ron Poisoned') by the music box @1:08:02 - 1:08:12

***PHEW*** Now I can sleep tonight!?!

Answer (score 0):

The song in the beginning has a very similar sound to the vocals of the popular song "Just a Friend" by Biz Markie.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could make this a better answer by linking to the song on YouTube or a similar site.

Comment: And to a specific time frame as I'm not hearing the connection at all (thanks for posting though :-) )